# Local file phonegap with online building app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, audio, phonegap-build

I'm new to phonegap and I need to know where to put files in a local folder and how to access them. I tried to build my app in my computer with eclipse and so on, but there is too much stuff to install, user variables, command lines ... I tried but it doesn't work and I don't know where is the problem, then I tried to build my app from [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com/) and it worked perfectly. The problem I have is that I need to read an audio file, I tried the `Audio` object, and the `Media` object, but they don't work.

I looked for the solution and I found that you have to put your local files in `assets/` or `android_assets/` and you need to access them, I don't know how

```
/assets/file.wav
file:///android_assets/file.wav
```

so I started adding folders like `assets/`, `android_assets/`, `audios/`, `whatever/` but nothing works.

can you please tell me where to put my files and how to access them. **no command lines, no eclipse**... just manually before building the app from [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com/)

Comment: All resources media put into www folder or anywhere, and path to access to it in Android is "file:///android_asset/www/". In IOS you not need add full path, only need path file: 'path from www to'.

Comment: please explain to me, I have a file index.html and a folder audio that contain my file, I need to access this file, should I create a folder android_asset or www ... ?? or I should keep my folder audio and access my file with file://andoird_asset/www/audio/file.wav

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful link, that maybe helps: [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Have you installed the file plugin? Because this is necessary for it. If not, first of all you need to install it,  type in the command line in the project's folder this command (it isn't hard):

**cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file**

According to the file plugin documentation, the best place is to store files is the following path:

**file:///data/data/{app-id}/files/files/{your folder}/{your files}**

For example:  file:///data/data/com.phonegap.myapp/files/files/audio/file.wav

This is persistent, readable/writable, the os doesn't clear it and private. 
*"Persistent and private data storage within the application's sandbox using internal memory"*

Within your program you can refer it this way: **cordova.file.dataDirectory**

For example here is a code from my app that download an image from a URL and put it to HTML in an image tag:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,function(fileSystem) {    
                var imageURL = "http://example.com/image.jpeg";
                var ext = imageURL.substr(imageURL.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); //extension of the image
                var relativeFilePath = "images/myimage" + "." + ext;
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.download(imageURL, fileSystem.root.toURL() + relativeFilePath, function(entry) {
                    var myImage= "<img src=" + fileSystem.root.toURL() + relativeFilePath + "' id=" + "imageID" + ">";
                    alert(fileSystem.root.toURL() + relativeFilePath);   //kép
                    $('#imgdiv').html(myImage);
                }, function(err) { alert("Download failure: " + JSON.stringify(err)); });
            }, function(err) { alert("requestFileSystem failure: " + JSON.stringify(err)); });
```

In this code the fileSystem.root.toURL() refers to  file:///data/data/com.phonegap.myapp/files/files/

and relativeFilePath is created by me, refers to images/myimage.jpeg

(for the download you need the file-transfer plugin, you can install with the

*cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer* command).

I hope this helps.

Comment: when I run the commande `cordova plugin ...` it says the current working directory is not a cordova-based project

Comment: Here is a link about what have to do: [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). If you have created the Phonegap project this way: _cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld_ , where _hello_ is the directory name, _com.example.hello_ is your app ID, and _HelloWorld_ is the app display title. Then you go in the project folder with _cd hello_ command and add android platform with _cordova platform add android_ . Here have you to write the _cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file_ command. [Doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/)

Comment: Nothing worked at all, I've tried building by ui, and by command lines, everythings is ok until the test of the app, the file is not found

Comment: this is the perfect solution for me. thanks a lot man, searching for this for hours. and my problem solved by this solution. thanks a lot man @spaghetti_code

Answer (score -1):

@Khalid You must create project manually:

```
project_folder
  |___index.html
  |___audio_folder
  |___any resources or folder
```

Please check document from Phonegap Build

Edit 1: To play media file by Media object

```
// Get path 'www' in Android
function getPathApp(){
  return location.href.slice(0,-10);
}
var media = new Media(getPathApp() + 'audio/file.wav');

// In IOS only need path from audio folder
var media = new Media('audio/file.wav');

media.play();
```

Comment: okey, then what's the path to use ?? because from `index.html` the path `audio_folder/file.wav` doesn't work

Comment: I did all this but how to access the files inside the `audio_folder` is the question